# Loop through arrays with multiple columns and rows

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I've done a lot of searching to try and optimize this code.  I've reduced the run time down significantly, but I can't seem to find anything else (note: I've done all the xlcalculationmanual and screenupdating = false jazz)

Here is the basic structure of my current loop. The matrix is currently 5 rows down with data to loop through and 9 across.

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
i = 0
Do While wsc1.Cells(10, i + 65) <> "things" And wsc1.Cells(10, i + 65) <> "thing2" And wsc1.Cells(10, i + 65) <> ""
    j = 0
    Do While wsc1.Cells(j + 11, 64) <> ""
        wsc.Cells(109, 3) = wsc1.Cells(j + 11, 64)    'rows
        wsc.Cells(109, 6) = wsc1.Cells(10, i + 65)    'columns
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        wsc1.Cells(j + 11, i + 65) = wsc.Range("O6")    'Print
        j = j + 1
    Loop
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

I assume my next best option is storing the column/row vector as a variant and looping through that?

Thanks

Comment: What formula is in cell O6?  Do you have to rely to on recalculating the result in O6 based on the values in C109 and F109?  It's possible this could be done via code.

Comment: I do.  It links to something that is recalculated while the loop runs.  O6 basically links to a much larger calculation that changes based on what I'm looping through here.

Comment: If you could write your code to work in a VBA variant array, and only read/write to the worksheet once (well, twice - once at the beginning and once at the end), my experience is that you are may see as much as a 10-fold speed increase, compared with multiple worksheet accesses.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Can you also add these lines?

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' it seems that you already have this one?
```

Comment: I've added that already.  It's a bigger optimization than those Application. optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.  However, having to wait for the sheet calculation is a pretty hard slowdown, there's really not much that can be done beyond this to improve performance if we can't put the calculations in the code.

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wsc1 As Worksheet
    Dim CValues As Variant
    Dim FValues As Variant
    Dim Results() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim xlCalc As XlCalculation

    With Application
        xlCalc = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    On Error GoTo CleanExit

    Set wsc1 = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    With wsc1.Range("BL11", wsc1.Cells(wsc1.Rows.Count, "BL").End(xlUp))
        If .Row < 11 Then Exit Sub 'No data
        If .Cells.Count = 1 Then
            ReDim CValues(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
            CValues(1, 1) = .Value
        Else
            CValues = .Value
        End If
    End With

    With wsc1.Range("BM10", wsc1.Cells(10, wsc1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
        If .Column < Columns("BM").Column Then Exit Sub 'No data
        If .Cells.Count = 1 Then
            ReDim FValues(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
            FValues(1, 1) = .Value
        Else
            FValues = .Value
        End If
    End With

    ReDim Results(1 To UBound(CValues, 1), 1 To UBound(FValues, 2))

    For i = LBound(CValues, 1) To UBound(CValues, 1)
        For j = LBound(FValues, 2) To UBound(FValues, 2)
            wsc1.Range("C109").Value = CValues(i, 1)
            wsc1.Range("F109").Value = FValues(1, j)
            wsc1.Calculate
            Results(i, j) = wsc1.Range("O6").Value
        Next j
    Next i

    wsc1.Range("BM11").Resize(UBound(Results, 1), UBound(Results, 2)).Value = Results

CleanExit:
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalc
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I think this is generally what I'm trying to program myself.  wsc1 and wsc in the code I posted are from separate sheets I defined, I guess my main question is around getting the looping through the array correct, which you use here, but I probably need to just mess with it since my version is giving me an error.  This at least gets me started